# upgrade fipl/whoops 2.* in laravel 4.2.*

Tags: php-7, laravel-4.2, whoops

I using laravel 4.2.19 with php7 then have problem with Exception, I search and see problem in php7 remove Exception class and fipl/whoops 1.* then not working but upgrade to version 2.* then will working with php7.
[images error when require fipl/whoops 2.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGCyc.png)

And my problem how to upgrade fipl/whoops 1.* to 2.* in laravel 4.2.19 ?

Answer (score 0):

The image you shared shows that Laravel 4.2.x doesn't support the package version you are going to install.
The better is to upgrade from 4.2 to minimum 5.1 to use PHP7 without issues.